# Thumbnail for video in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, thumbnails

it woks from the cmd, but when debugging won't go into while condiion, any ideas why please ? Browsing for the site in IIS returns with exception : 
**System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied.**

```
        string video;
        string thumb;

        video = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Video/test.avi");
        thumb = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Video/frame.jpg");

        Process proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Video/ffmpeg.exe"),
                Arguments = " -i " + video + " -ss 00:00:03 -vframes 1 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg " + thumb,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        proc.Start();
        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the user security context of the IIS process does not have the rights to run the application.

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure that the application pool user has rights to run ffmpeg.exe

Comment: I'm new to asp.net and was just using the built in server in VS2010. Any tutorial on how to quickly set the site up with IIS 7 and where to set up the proper rights? Thank you again !

Comment: I modified the code a bit for debugging purposes. But cannot get it to work.

Comment: @Chuchelo There is nothing you can do in your code to get rid of this exception, you just need to configure properly your IIS and the security permissions on the folders involved.

Comment: You can use Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see to what precise resource your security context is being denied access. Be forewarned - PM will give you a lot of data, but learning to filter it out and work with it is a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: It is running now, and I can see the prompt starting and even see ffmpeg.exe appearing on the prompt, but since it disappearing so fast I cannot see why the thumbnail is not generating. I assume the permissions are fine now and something is wrong with the code ?

Comment: After setting proper application pool rights, the problem was with the path, it was not escaping the spaces. Thank you again.